# Using PHP to upload file add path to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

i want to upload file on folder upload and save the link on my table under name Link1. it keep give me the following  errors at php side

> Notice: Undefined index: link1 in C:\wamp\www\1\1.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: link1 in C:\wamp\www\1\1.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: link1 in C:\wamp\www\1\1.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: link1 in C:\wamp\www\1\1.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uploads/ in C:\wamp\www\1\1.php on line 21

can anybody tell me where is the wrong in my code, i do not want use upload.php i want all my work to be at the same page. thank you.

```
 <?php
        include 'db_connection.php';    
        if(isset($_POST['finish'])){


          $file_name = $_FILES['link1']['name'];
          $file_size =$_FILES['link1']['size'];
          $file_tmp =$_FILES['link1']['tmp_name'];
          $file_type=$_FILES['link1']['type'];
          move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);

            $name       = '"'.$dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['name']).'"';
            $Mobile         = '"'.$dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['Mobile']).'"';
            $civilid    = '"'.$dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['civilid']).'"';
            $bulildingnumber        = '"'.$dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['bulildingnumber']).'"';
            $province       = '"'.$dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['province']).'"';
            $area       = '"'.$dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['area']).'"';
            $block  = '"'.$dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['block']).'"';
            $house  = '"'.$dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['house']).'"';
            $contractdata       = '"'.$dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['contractdata']).'"';
            $projecttype        = '"'.$dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['projecttype']).'"';
    $link1      = '"'.$dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST[$file_name]).'"';


            $sqlInsertUser = $dbConnection->query("INSERT INTO users (name, Mobile, civilid, bulildingnumber,area,block,house,contractdata, projecttype,province,Link1) VALUES($name, $Mobile, $civilid, $bulildingnumber,$area,$block,$house,$contractdata, $projecttype,$province,$link1)");

            if($sqlInsertUser === false){
                $message = 'Error: ' . $dbConnection->error;
            }else{
                $message =  'Last inserted record is : ' .$dbConnection->insert_id ; 
            }
        }
    ?>
```

here is my HTML code to pick the file

```
<label>Decumnets needed</label>
     <div><input type="file" name="link1" id="link1" class="InputBox" /></div>
```

Comment: I am hoping that not everything you wrote on your html file, i hope u have a form and its enctype property =multipart/form-data thats contains that html otherwise it wont work

Comment: Please specify what error you are getting

Comment: Yes i wrote the form but the problem is up at php section.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: link1 in C:\wamp\www\1\1.php on line 6

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: link1 in C:\wamp\www\1\1.php on line 7

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: uploads/ in C:\wamp\www\1\1.php on line 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you did't set the `enctype` attribute for your Form. Without it, php won't be able to find the file. `<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">` should work for you. I have something similar:
`<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="8000000">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="caption" placeholder="Enter Caption">
    <inputtype="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>`

And it works for me.